# What is a selective constraint?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, terminology, population-genetics

I encountered the term *selective constraint* in [Huber et al. 2015](http://biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/early/2015/04/30/018697.full.pdf), page 4 (last paragraph) in:

> If invariable  sites are included in the   analysis, then both the methods of
>   Kim   and Stephan (2002)  and Nielsen et  al. (2005)  may be  sensitive
>   to    assumptions regarding selective constraint  and mutation rates.

but the context does not quite help.

**What it the definition of selective constraint?**

Does it has to do with lethal mutations in non-coding regions? Does it has to do with selection interference?...

Comment: Please use the *quote environment* instead of the *code environment* (as far as I know most screen readers will start reading this character-by-character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is selective pressure that determines and limits the number of neutral/beneficial mutations that can take place. The more constrained a locus is under selection, the easier it is to generate deleterious mutations and the harder it is to generate beneficial ones; this can be reflected in low substitution rates at such loci in populations with time.

One widely used method to measure this is to compute the Ka/Ks ratio to infer if a locus is selectively constrained or not.

Comment: +1 Thank you. Can we associate a value to this concept? For example the  selective constrained could be $S = K_a/K_a$ or $S = mu_b/mu_d$, where $mu_b$ and $mu_d$ are the beneficial and deleterious mutation rates, respectively.

Comment: It is easier to measure Ka and Ks , so if something is under no selection (neutral) you'll see a ratio of 1 , less than 1 indicates purifying selection, more than 1 indicates positive selection. More here http://www.cs.mun.ca/~banzhaf/papers/ppsn08_evorate.pdf